# Is there a way to determine the line of code that causes a type to be loaded?

Tags: c#, roslyn, typeloadexception

The problem is that I often get a TypeLoadReflectionException and my ability to find the cause for them is very limited, essentially nil actually. 
Today I again had a problem like this and couldn't solve it. For some reason my assembly required another assembly which never happened before and even reverting the code to a previously working state did not fix the issue. I'm stumped, there must be deeper issues here.

Is there any way to debug this properly? Ideally a tool like Reflector or IlSpy would be ably to tell me "dependent assemblies" and "type dependencies" per line. 
Seeing as how the C# 4.5 Roslyn compiler is now open source, this should theoretically be doable, after all the compiler at some point during the compilation process decides "hey, i need this type for this stuff to compile". Correct? However these TypeLoadExceptions occur at runtime, so I'm not sure.

Comment: What is the data in the TypeLoadReflectionException instance your code throws? I mean Message, InnerException, CallStack?

Comment: Eugene, this happened on an InstallUtil.exe call. The fusion log just says that it's trying to find the dll at whatever locations it's looking for. The issue is that I dont know why it needs that dll in the first place.

Comment: Attach a debugger, break on `TypeLoadReflectionException`, profit.

Comment: that doesnt tell me who is causing the type to be loaded, just which type is trying to be loaded at best.